# Is it necessary to validate function parameters or not?

Tags: php

When i write down a function is a good practice to validate all the parameters of the function like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * foo - Test function
 *
 * @param int $paramA
 * @param str $paramB
 * @param array $paramC
 *
 * @return something
 */
function foo($paramA, $paramB, $paramC) {
    // verify all parameters
    if(!is_int($paramA)) {
        return 0; // or error msg
    }
    if(!is_string($paramB)) {
        return 1; // or error msg
    }
    if(!is_array($paramC)) {
        return 2; // or error msg
    }

    // some code in function scope that uses parameters 
    // and saves the results in $result
    return $result;
}
```

or should i rely on the user that will use the function and assume that he knows what he is doing and forget about parameter validation?

Personally i prefer to validate all the parameter of the function and return error codes for consistency of the code and make my life easier afterwords.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, of course it is... a *great practice*. **Necessary**? Well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an internal function that only you will be using, it is probably okay to not validate every single parameter like that. If it is a function that has parameters that depend on user input (for example, you get information through `$_GET`, and then pass that to a function), then it needs to be validated.

Never rely on a user or anyone else besides yourself to know what they are doing. Sometimes it can be helpful to validate things like this if you are writing code that you can re-use later (like if you were writing your own framework to use across all of your PHP projects). But if it is just one application-specific function that only you can call with parameters that only you define, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: As far as your second sentence, first paragraph: It *is* **necessary** to always validate, clean, escape, cast, and/or otherwise *prove* the submitted data is what it should be and is free of "unnecessary" content.

Comment: Of course. I changed "should be validated" to "needs to be validated" for clarity.

Comment: With `$_GET` especially, not validating user input can open a big security hole.

Comment: -1, see my comment on watcher's post.  I was hesitant to -1 though, as it does point out not to trust user input.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is: **it depends**

It depends on who you are writing your code for.  If you're looking for the *most generalized* answer, then **yes**, you should.

If your script will only ever be used by you and you know in your heart of hearts that you will always use it correctly, then you will (probably) be safe if you don't.

If your script is part of an API that will be distributed to many, many people, then you most definitely want to add error checking and provide good fall back error messages for people.

If you are part of a small team that will all be using the same code, I would also suggest that validating your arguments according to your particular context would be a good idea.

Comment: -1, it doesn't depend.  You check those parameters.  You check them every time.  You don't trust anyone, not even yourself.

Comment: @LeviMorrison I don't agree with you. First of all, checking for every parameter in every function will surely increase code length as well as the time required to code it. This can result in quite some wasted time for larger projects. In addition, you'll be checking the same parameters over and over again as the values get passed through the application. Premature optimization is obviously bad, but I am guessing this might cause some performance overhead.

Comment: @Gilden Oh, it will take longer to code and might add some burden to your code.  What happens in C++ when you don't check your parameters?  Segmentation faults.  What happens in PHP when you don't check your parameters?  Unknown results.  In some ways, that's even worse than seg faults. . .

Comment: I also disagree.  You want to tell me that in every single function/method in every single language you will always sanitize your parameters?  What if the function is being called in a tight loop and is embedded in a real time application?  If you waste time checking all of your parameters, you'll wind up losing more cycles than you can waste.  Blindly saying that you do it every time is _not_ correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Why validate your parameters:**

- **Sometimes we really need a certain datatype for an operation.**  If you give me a string that is not representative of an integer and you use that as a search for a primary key in a database (usually an int), then you will have trouble.
- **It makes fixing your code easier.** When you are checking parameters, you can throw individual exceptions and give messages that are very descriptive.  This makes it easier to fix your code when something breaks, because you know exactly what went wrong.

**Some tips on type checking:**

- **In case you didn't know, `is_int` is pretty faulty.**  I think a valid check to see if it is an int is `is_numeric($int) && $int==(int)$int`.
- **You can specify types for objects and arrays**, like so: `function foo($paramA, $paramB, array $paramC)`.

Comment: And, there's probably a good reason why http://fluffykittypics.com doesn't get written in C++.

Comment: Thank you for your information, i didn'y know that is_int is faulty.

Comment: @Starlays I just updated my answer to include some reasons you should validate your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the type-strictness of what you're doing with those parameters.

Since PHP is weakly typed, you can get away with a lot by casting or just letting the implicit type conversion/coercion do it's thing.

And if you're just going to throw a bunch of guard conditions at the head of every function only to return errors, that's really not much different than PHP triggering errors of its own.

Comment: And if you're just going to throw a bunch of guard conditions at the head of every function only to return errors, that's really not much different than PHP triggering errors of its own.

What do you mean by that? How can php trigger an error for my functions parameters? I`m confused.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't depend on auto-conversions.  You should do basic checking.  It doesn't really matter if it's `'1'` or `1`, but it WILL matter if you are expecting `1` and got `'id1'`.

Answer (score 0):

I beg to differ. I recently stumbled upon [an article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=168511) about a similar issue (null checks), but it seems to apply for type checking in php as well. I agree with the author.

- Write code in a way that makes type checking redundant.
- **explicitly validate user input** and cast the values to the required types as soon as possible.
- In some exceptional cases, you can and should use exceptions instead of returning some obscure error numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very good practice to validate function arguments. I suspect you ask this question because on the other hand it makes your functions look longer and uglier. However with [args module](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#nsplargs) from [NSPL](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl), it is very easy to do. The function from your example will be:

```
function foo($paramA, $paramB, array $paramC) 
{
    expects(int, $paramA);
    expects(string, $paramB);

    // do something
}

// or type check several arguments
function sum($x, $y)
{
    expectsAll(numeric, [$x, $y]);
    return $x + $y;
}
```

More examples [here](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl/blob/master/examples/args.php).